# Hadoop program stuck at "Running job:"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I was running hadoop program (wordcount) in Horton sandbox. And the situation occurred as below. Especially, this is the program I had ran successfully for many times on exactly the same virtual machine I used, however this time it "failed" without any notification, so it just stuck there. I tried other mapreduce program, the results are similar. Normally, the command lines will notify me with `ubermode : false`, follows by the `Running job...`, but this time, it doesn't, and out of no reason.

```
[root@sandbox ~]# hadoop jar testWC.jar testWC.WCdriver /data/input/pg103.txt /data/output/WC
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
16/03/11 19:20:01 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/03/11 19:20:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8050
16/03/11 19:20:01 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/03/11 19:20:02 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/03/11 19:20:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/03/11 19:20:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1457723341319_0002
16/03/11 19:20:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1457723341319_0002
16/03/11 19:20:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1457723341319_0002/
16/03/11 19:20:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1457723341319_0002
```

The program just could not move on anymore.

Comment: when you open the application URL `http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1457723341319_0002/` what do you see? sometimes the application ends up waiting for a lot of time to gather container resources to run your application.